# Extracting text from text file based on pattern in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file that has the following format:

```
str = '{"controversiality":0,"body":"A look at Vietnam and Mexico liberalisation.","subreddit_id":"t5_6"}{"subreddit_id":"t5_6", "controversiality":0,"body":"I need a cup of water."}';
```

I want to extract the body tag from `str` in this format :

```
A look at Vietnam and Mexico liberalisation.
I need a cup of water.
```

Comment: And how did you try to do that?

Comment: Looks like you're working with `json` - you might want to take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Answer (score 1):

for this format of data instead of .txt file its better to use JSON file format.
for example:
files structure:

```
.
├── data.json
└── parser.py
```

`data.json`

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "controversiality": 0,
            "body": "A look at Vietnam and Mexico liberalisation.",
            "subreddit_id": "t5_6"
        },
        {
            "subreddit_id": "t5_6",
            "controversiality": 0,
            "body": "I need a cup of water."
        }
    ]
}
```

reading Json data 
`parser.py`

```py
import json

with open('data.json') as e:
    data = json.load(e)

json_data = data['data']
for j in json_data:
    if j.get('body'):
        print(j['body'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Each segment of the string enclosed in {} is in JSON format. The `json` library can be used to make accessing data easy, turning it into a dictionary. For example:

```
import json
post_str = '{"controversiality":0,"body":"A look at Vietnam and Mexico liberalisation.","subreddit_id":"t5_6"}'
post_json = json.loads(post_str)
body = post_json['body']
```

Your example is a little trickier because each post does not appear to be separated nicely, for example, if each post was on a new line it would be trivial to process the file line-by-line. Ideally, you'd save the data as a JSON file, as Giorgi has suggested, but if you're past the data collection stage, the following will work with your current data, but is a little ugly:

```
import json
str = '{"controversiality":0,"body":"A look at Vietnam and Mexico liberalisation.","subreddit_id":"t5_6"}{"subreddit_id":"t5_6", "controversiality":0,"body":"I need a cup of water."}'
post_bodies = []
for post_str in str.split('}')[:-1]:
    post_str += '}'
    post = json.loads(post_str)
    post_bodies.append(post["body"])
desired_output = " ".join(post_bodies)
```